# document.getElementsByClassName('class1').className += ' class2';

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

ok, i have class 1, and i want to add another class style (class2) to this class 1.

how i do this?

and why this works:

```
document.getElementById("idteste").className += ' HighAsuka';
```

and this not?

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class1').className += ' class2';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the difference is `getElementById` returns a single element, whereas `getElementsByClassName` yields a collection of elements. On a single elements you can use `.className` as it is a property of that element.

Now to answer your main question; in order to add `class2` to all elements which have `class1` you do this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class1');
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].className += ' class2';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns a list of elements as you can see from Elements in getElementsByClassName

So you need to access the array element and then set class name

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0].className
```